# log4cxx set log file with daily log

Tags: c++, config, log4cxx

I use log4cxx for my c++ project and I use properties for log config,here is my situation I wanna log my project with daily log file such as

```
log4j.appender.fa.File=./Client{Data}.log
```

Is there any way to reach that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use daily rolling file appender.
Check this url. I hope it would be helpful for you.

http://tunatore.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/how-to-define-dailyrollingfileappender-in-log4j-properties-file/